# Is "oi" a valid pair of letters in esperanto?

Tags: pronunciation, word-formation, syllables

I haven't run into any words that have *oi* in them that I recall. Is it a valid construction? How is it pronounced if so?

Answer (score 6):

Searching [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) for “oi”, I found a lot of examples of words with that vowel combination. Here are some examples:

> - *s**oi**fo*
> - *her**oi**no*
> - *eg**oi**sto*
> - *k**oi**ncido*
> - *tr**oi**go*
> - …

As for pronounciation, as usual in Esperanto, it is “read what you see”. :) That is, it should be clear that it is *“o”* then *“i”*. One should not read it as if it was *“oj”* but I cannot give much more advice as I am not much of an expert on explaining pronounciation.

Comment: Phonetically there'd be a 'glottal stop' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop) between the 'o' and the 'i', so they're pronounced as two separate sounds. You can see that they are on morpheme boundaries, ie where two word components come together, never within a single unit.

Comment: @OliverMason no, there's no glottal stop; a glottal stop is when you suddenly close off the airflow in your throat (as in some pronunciations of "t"); a very noticeable sound. Also, you can see that "soifo" and "koincido" have "oi" within the same root.

Comment: It is a glottal stop. Trust me, I studied phonetics at uni :) It's the same root, but technically separate morphemes. 'ko' in 'koincido' is etymologically a different morpheme.

Comment: @OliverMason I do not think a glottal stop is used that much to delimit morphemes in Esperanto - though many people use it in correlatives ([tiʔel] etc) because it is difficult not to pronounce a glide there.

Comment: @OliverMason Could not that depend on where the accent is? I could see a glottal stop in _egoisto_, but not _koincido_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno unless you pronounce it like engl. 'coin' there is a glottal stop. It doesn't have to be as strong as in the Cockney 'bottle' /bo?el/, but even in engl 'coincidence' you have one.

Comment: @OliverMason It might be a localized issue - since a glotal stop is not phonemic in Esperanto, you are free to insert it, but I do not think I've heard it in these positions (it would certainly be discouraged in some/many natural languages in cognates of these words). I'll try to listen carefully when I have the next oportunity.

Comment: @OliverMason "unless you pronounce it like engl. 'coin' there is a glottal stop"
This is wrong. There are more ways to have a syllable boundary between two vowels than the glottal stop.

One way to say "soifo" without glottal stop is holding your mouth at the [o] position for a while, quickly glide to the [i] position, and then hold that position. Long [o], tiny [oi̯], long [i].

You can even pronounce "coincide" without glottal stop this way. (The [ʊ] in the middle almost sounds like a /w/ then.) In fact, I think most English speakers pronounce it this way at normal conversation speeds.

Answer (score 3):

There is a syllable boundary between the "o" and the "i" ("i" is the next syllable in fact). This is especially noticeable when the "i" becomes stressed, and even more noticeable when the speaker lengthens stressed syllables. A diphthong would be written "oj" and considered a vowel+consonant phonemically.